Monte Carlo Sampling for Optimal Replacement Time - Confidence Intervals
Barlow et al. (1960) described a function for optimal replacement time (ORT) estimation
$T^*(t) = \frac{C_{P} \cdot S(t)+C_{C}\cdot (1-S(t))}{\int^t_0S(\tau)d\tau}$
where $C_{P}$ is the preventive maintenance cost, $C_C$ is corrective maintenance cost and $S(t)$ is the survival function.
I want to run a Monte Carlo simulation to quantify the uncertainty of the ORT estimation. I assume a uniform distribution of the costs, but I also want to sample survival functions within the Confidence Intervals (CI). For the survival function, I use a Weibull or Kaplan Meier estimator. The CI of the survival functions is estimated using the Greenwood. I have several options:

Normal sample from the estimated Weibull parameters and their CI.
Normal sample survival functions using the variance estimated in the Greenwood.
Uniformly sample the $\alpha$ (CI) parameter of the Greenwood to generate a new survival function for each simulation.

What is the best method for uncertainty quantification when using these models? Is it one of the above, or are there other known methods?
Reference:

Barlow, R., & Hunter, L. (1960). Optimum preventive maintenance policies. Operations research, 8(1), 90-100.
Sawyer, S. (2003). The greenwood and exponential greenwood confidence intervals in survival analysis. Applied survival analysis: regression modeling of time to event data, 1-14.

